# Follow-up Intents for Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, api-ai

[This is the sample conversation. I am encountering a problem linking Follow-Up Intent (4) back to Follow-Up Intent (1).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgQzL.png)I am creating a DialogFlow agent. In this agent, there are two community clubs with their respective events, courses and facilities. My idea is to create an intent each for both community clubs. Within each intent(1), there will be three follow up intents(2), and within these intents there will be their respective information(3) (e.g. time, date, venue etc).

Within the follow-up intent (3), the users have to answer a series of yes or no follow-up intents (4). Basically the idea is that the follow-up intents will go pretty deep in, as such is there a way to link follow-up intents (4) back to follow-up intents (2)?

I hope this is not too confusing. Hope to hear from you soon!

Best Regards

Comment: It is confusing. Please share the conversation flow if you have like - User: <......> Bot: <......>, User: <......> Bot: <......>

Comment: Hi there, I added a picture in the post. Hope it helps!

Comment: Overall, I think you ought to check out more information on [conversation design in the Actions on Google docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/design/). I'm not sure about the current structure you have.